# JavaFX: in WebView img tag is not loading local images

Tags: java, html, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

Following is my code. Everything is fine. I can load a remote page. I can put HTML content but my `img` tag shows a ***X*** sign meaning that it is not able to load the images.

**Note:** My images are located in the same package along with the class `JavaFX` in a folder Smiley and I can list all the images which means there is not problem with the path.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JavaFX {
    static WebView webView;
    static WebEngine webEngine;
    static String imgs = "";

    public JavaFX() {
        File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/Smiley").getFile());
        for (File fs : f.listFiles()) {
            imgs += "<img src=\""+fs+"\" width='50' />";
        }
        System.out.println(imgs);
    }
    
    private void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on Swing thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FX");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initFX(final JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
        webView = new WebView();

        group.getChildren().add(webView);
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.loadContent("<div id='content'>"+imgs+"</div>");      
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JavaFX fx = new JavaFX();
                fx.initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Following is output

[image: Output of the above program]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help, I got the Following very simple solution

```
imgs += "<img src=\""+fs.toURI()+"\" width='50'>";
```

the image path must be converted to URI or URL to make the webView able to read it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("Smiley.png");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Comment: explain how to use the code and why this might be a solution to the probblem

Comment: @Sanket Pipariya Thanks for your answer the problems is not with the path the path is correct and I can list all the files in the directory but it is not rendered in the WebView using img tag!!!

Comment: dear @RuneFS and Sanket Pipariya I solved the problem see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26451542/1966247

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to read the file paths also via `getClass().getResource()`:

```
    for (File fs : f.listFiles()) {
        imgs += "<img src=\"" + getClass().getResource(fs.getName()) + "\" width='50' />";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dear for your help :) , I solved the Problem  see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26451542/1966247